# Find the eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix A defined by
$$
        A=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        -1& 2 &-1 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Find the eigenvalues of the matrix A.
2. Find the associated eigenvectors based on the answer in part (1)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried and where are you stuck? Regards

Comment: For section 1 i get C1 = 4, C2 = -3, C3 = 0

Comment: And do you know how to find the eigen-spaces of eigen-vectors?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- For the eigenvalues, setup and solve $|A - \lambda I| = 0$. Using the characteristic polynomial, you will find three distinct real eigenvalues $(0, 1, 3)$.
- For the eigenvectors, setup and solve $[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$, that is, solve that system for $v_i$ for each of the eigenvalues.

**Update**

Do you see how to get the characteristic polynomial from $|A - \lambda I| = 0$?

We have:

$$[A-\lambda I] = \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & -1 & 0\\-1& 2-\lambda &-1\\0 & -1 & 1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant is given by:

$(1-\lambda)((2-\lambda)(1-\lambda) -1)+(-1)(1-\lambda) = -\lambda^3+4 \lambda^2-3 \lambda$

Thus,

$$-\lambda^3+4 \lambda^2-3 \lambda = -(\lambda-3) (\lambda-1) \lambda = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = 1, \lambda_3 = 3$$

Comment: Can u be more specific plz

Comment: @LOLA: See update for part 1. Do you understand how to take the determinant of the 3x3 to get the CP?

Comment: I get λ^3 -4λ^2-3λ=0, but how did u get yours?

Comment: Did you mess up a sign when doing cofactors? See update.

Comment: Lets check, did you write the matrix correctly (to eliminate that too)?

Comment: Nice work, and follow-up comments! Let's hope it "takes"!